# How to handle Questions without answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, vote-to-close

I have reached a point where I believe an answer to my question is highly unlikely.

Here is the question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42713/is-there-a-visual-building-tool-to-generate-linq-queries

It clearly shows (from the credible answer of a reputed member and my numerous google searches) the likeliness of a proper solution to this question is not imminent.

Is closing it, following the forum's etiquette? If not could you please suggest alternatives as I feel bothered to just leave it lingering around.

Note: This applies to other questions on the forum of the same nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done what I usually do if a Q bcomes old without getting proper attention: closed it as too localized.

Feel free to flag other Qs as that if. They represent some relatively unique problem that, even though relevant is too localized to make sense as a Q in this forum

Comment: With this question, I would of voted it up, since it is a good question and it has an answer. There is a project for generating the LINQ Query from any collection object, and it has a link to show you how to generate queries at runtime. This would of been my answer, imo I think it's always worth an upvote so it gets pushed to unanswered, where many people go on the hunt for points. Obviously if the question is a stupid one, then close/remove it. Or am I wrong in this notion?